# Having multiple Ids on linq-sql join query in c#

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a `linq-to-sql` query that fetches records.

First of all, I have a variable that can hold an Id or multiple Ids.

```
var consumerId = _context.Consumers.Where(x => x.UsrDefault.Equals("True"));
// This can return one or an array of Ids.
```

Then, I have a linq-to-sql query as follows:

```
var query = (from users in _context.Users 
            join consumers in _context.Consumers 
            on usersId equals consumerId 
            select new UserConsumerDto 
            {
             FirstName = users.FirstName, 
             LastName = users.LastName
            }).ToList()
```

My question is that when I have multiple `consumerId`, how can I perform this `linq-to-sql` query ? I want to avoid any foreach loop.

Can someone please advise ?

Comment: If it's an array of Id then equality would never work right. Rather you will have to make it a `IN` clause (`Contains()`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Contains` is the method to be used here or `Any()`.

See the code snippet below:

```
var query = (from users in _context.Users 
            join consumers in _context.Consumers 
            on users.usersId equals consumers.consumerId 
            where consumerId.Contains(consumers.consumerId)
            select new UserConsumerDto 
            {
             FirstName = users.FirstName, 
             LastName = users.LastName
            }).ToList()
```

for any :

```
where consumerId.Any(id => id == consumers.consumerId)
```

Comment: Assalamualaikum Ehsan. Thanks you for your answer. 

Another way of doing this could be: `join consumers on 
    consumers.Id IN (consumerId)` 

Do you advise this ?

Comment: Walaikum Salaam, i am not sure if it will be translated to proper sql, can be tried if it works

Comment: Thank you for your help brother :)